# Is a change of coordinates the same thing as a change of chart on a manifold?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I am familiar with coordinate transformations in the common case. (Say, polar to cartesian and back)

I have recently been introduced to the definition of a differentiable manifold. Is it correct to say that, in Newtonian physics for instance, if you are transforming a vector from Cartesian to Polar, what you are doing is mapping the vector from one chart to another and expressing it in the coordinate-induced basis of the new chart?

Comment: Two comments: (1) this probably belongs in Math.SE rather than Physics and (2) 'Yes' is too short an answer to post...

Comment: Yes a chart on a configuration manifold I guess

Comment: Yes. Indeed too short.

Comment: I can't accept an answer because as you said, "Yes" is too short, but I want to say thank you for providing me with the answer to my question.